# Golang regexp to match string until a given sequence of characters

Tags: regex, go

I have a string that could have a -name followed by value (that can have spaces) and there could also be -descr after that followed by a value (the -descr followed by value may nor may not be there):

Example strings:

```
runcmd -name abcd xyz -descr abc def
```

or

```
runcmd -name abcd xyz
```

With Go language, how do I write regexp, that returns me the string before -descr if it exists. so, for both examples above, the result should be:

```
runcmd -name abcd xyz
```

I was trying:

```
regexp.MustCompile(`(-name ).+?=-descr`)
```

But, that did not return any match. I wanted to know the correct regexp to get the string up until -descr if it exists

Comment: When you say something "does not work", it's important to explain *how* - error, incorrect behavior (and specify what), etc. Just from looking at the code, however, your regex is looking for a string with an `=` in it, but you exemplars do not contain that character.

Comment: If you can use a capturing group, try `^(.*? -name.*?)(?: *-descr|$)` [demo](https://regex101.com/r/XDEJ89/1)

Comment: Should `-descr` be there? Because it is not in the second example.

Comment: @Thefourthbird, will this capturing group work with Golang? Can you tell the syntax to use with regex.MustCompile?

Comment: I want to exclude -descr from the match

Comment: I mean should you also match `runcmd -name abcd xyz` when there is no `-descr` following?

Comment: Yes, when there is no -descr, it should match and return `runcmd -name abcd xyz`

Comment: Why use a regex for such a simple task?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could capturin first part with `-name` in a group, then match what is in between and use an optional second capturing group to match `-descr` and what follows.

Then you could use the capturing groups when creating the desired result.

```
^(.*? -name\b).*?(-descr\b.*)?$
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/EVcK4n/1/) | [Go demo](https://ideone.com/V6bGpF)

For example:

```
s := "runcmd -name abcd xyz -descr abc def"
re1 := regexp.MustCompile(`^(.*? -name\b).*?(-descr\b.*)?$`)
result := re1.FindStringSubmatch(s)
fmt.Printf(result[1] + "..." + result[2])
```

Result:

```
runcmd -name...-descr abc def
```

Comment: Is it possible to modify this so the first group only contains uptil -name? The reason is, I would eventually need to do something like re1.ReplaceAllString(s, "$1"+"...."+" ")), so I can return the original string just with the value of -name replaced with ...., so the output string becomes `runcmd -name .... -descr abc def` which is the final goal

Comment: @user1892775 To get only the first group you could use `^(.*? -name)` [demo](https://regex101.com/r/ojNnBl/2). In that case you could also use just a match instead `^.*? -name` [demo](https://regex101.com/r/ojNnBl/1) and it could look like this [Go demo](https://ideone.com/GScvjs)

Comment: Not sure, if I was clear enough, I want to modify the regexp so that s := "runcmd -name abcd xyz -descr abc def"
re1 := regexp.MustCompile(regexp) 
fmt.Println(re1.ReplaceAllString(s, "$1"+"...."+" "))
  should be `runcmd -name .... -descr abc def'

Comment: If you could share an example which would give that output (the string with value for -name replaced with ....) as indicated in the code above, that would really help

Comment: @user1892775 Do you mean like this using 2 capturing groups? https://ideone.com/vOTdLz

Comment: Sorry if its getting confusing. Let me try to make it simpler. For inputstr = "runcmd -name abcd xyz -descr abc def", I want the output to be "runcmd -name .... -descr abc def"

Comment: @user1892775 You could concatenate the groups https://ideone.com/aHwa3L

Comment: yeah, but then it seem to fail for the inputstr s = "runcmd -name abcd xyz"   (that is, when -descr option is missing)

Comment: @user1892775 In that case you can make the second capturing group optional https://ideone.com/V6bGpF

Comment: @user1892775 I have updated my answer with the latest example.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/186440/discussion-between-user1892775-and-the-fourth-bird).

Answer (score 0):

By "Does not work", do you mean it doesn't match anything, or just not what you expect?

https://regex101.com/ is generally very helpful when testing regular expressions.

I do not believe there's a simple way to achieve what you want. Things become a lot simpler if we can assume the text betweeen `-name` and `-descr` doesn't contain any `-` in which case, `` regex.MustCompile(`-name ([^-]*)`) `` should work

With this kind of thing, often it's easier and clearer to use 2 regular expressions. So the first strips `-descr` and anything following it, and the first matches `-name` and all subsequent characters.

Comment: Text betweeen -name and -descr doesn't contain any -

Answer (score 0):

You are not dealing with a regular language here, so there is no reason to bust out the (slow) regexp engine. The strings package is quite enough:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "strings"
    "unicode"
)

func main() {
    fmt.Printf("%q\n", f("runcmd -name abcd xyz -descr abc def"))
    fmt.Printf("%q\n", f("runcmd -name abcd xyz"))
    fmt.Printf("%q\n", f("-descr abc def"))
}

func f(s string) string {
    if n := strings.Index(s, "-descr"); n >= 0 {
        return strings.TrimRightFunc(s[:n], unicode.IsSpace)
    }
    return s
}

// Output:
// "runcmd -name abcd xyz"
// "runcmd -name abcd xyz"
// ""
```

Try it on the playground: https://play.golang.org/p/RFC65CYe6mp